# Django/Heroku: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dj_database_url

Tags: python, django, heroku

In my requirements.txt:

```
dj-database-url==0.5.0
psycopg2-binary==2.7.7
```

In setting.py

```
import dj_database_url
db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500)
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)
```

When I run:

```
heroku run python manage.py migrate
```

Error:

```
import dj_database_url
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dj_database_url'
```

I have also tried running:

```
heroku run pip install dj-database-url
```

It gets installed correctly, but the error is still there.

Comment: Have you pushed your changes to heroku's git remote after adding this requirement?

Comment: Yes, I have pushed the changes

Comment: Do you also have a `Pipfile` and / or `Pipfile.lock`? (Note that you can't interactively run `pip install` on Heroku and expect it to work correctly. *All* libraries *must* be installed at build time.)